# dojo.dnd.moveable with position:fixed

Tags: javascript, css, dojo, drag-and-drop

I try to use a dojo moveable with a fixed position in the browser window.
Unfortunatly everytime I move the div with the mouse the position is set to absolute. What can I do to make the div fixed ?

html:

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="moveMe" style="position:fixed;width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid black;background-color:#00ff00;cursor:pointer;">bla</div>
<p>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>
test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>
test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>
test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>
test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>test<br>
</body>
</html>
```

script:

```
dojo.require("dojo.dnd.move");
dojo.ready(function(){

    var pcm = new dojo.dnd.move.boxConstrainedMoveable(dojo.byId("moveMe"), {
        box : dojo.window.getBox(),
        within : true
    });

});
```

Link to test:
http://jsfiddle.net/zPVdX/

cheers,
krater

Comment: Its not supported by Dojo 1.8.0, but I found a quick and dirty way to patch it: http://codenaschen.de/tichyblog/index.php?action=blog&entry=14_Dojo%20DnD%20with%20position:fixed

Answer (score 0):

*position: fixed* and *position: absolute* are two completely opposing methods used by the browser to determine how an element is positioned.

I'd first recommend reading up on the differences between them: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Hopefully now you will understand why Dojo draggable needs to set your element to an absolute position. This allows Dojo to visually move the draggable element via it's *top:* and *left:* properties.

Compare this with static positioning, which will attempt to anchor your element to a position relative to the current viewport.

If you add more detail on what are you visually trying to accomplish, there may be another solution.

Comment: I read that, but I don't understand the big difference. I can set the position of fixed AND absolute elements with top and left. Only difference I see is that fixed doesn't scrolls with the content and absolute does.

look here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ss9ZZ/

What I want is the behavior of the green box in my example, plus the possibility to move the box with the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

You could use event `'MoveStop'` on your DND (draggable element) in order to forcefully add `position: fixed;` at the END of your drag action. In this way you would be able to drag around your element using `position: absolute;` and have it have fix position when the drag is finished.

Some pesudo code

```
  yourDnd.on('MoveStop', function (e) {
        // Set position FIXED
        domStyle.set(this.node, {
            'position': 'fixed ',
        });
    });
```

More info on events can be found here:

http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/dnd

Regarding [this hack](http://codenaschen.de/tichyblog/index.php?action=blog&entry=14_Dojo%20DnD%20with%20position:fixed) I would not suggest you to change DOJO library as your change could be not safe and create bugs in other part of the framework.

Answer (score 0):

I just got this working with:

> ```
>         dnd.on('MoveStart', function (e) {
>             var p = dojo.position(e.node, true);
>             var parent_position = dojo.position(e.node.parentNode, true)
>
>             dojo.style(e.node, "top", p.y - parent_position.y + "px");
>             dojo.style(e.node, "position", "absolute");
>         });
>         dnd.on('MoveStop', function (e) {
>             var p = dojo.position(e.node, false);
>             dojo.style(e.node, "top", p.y + "px");
>             dojo.style(e.node, "position", "fixed");
>         });
> ```